# How do you restrict user input and get booleans to work?

Tags: java

I am trying to complete this code. I can't seem to get it to restrict the characters input by the user to "H" or "L"; as well as get the boolean for playAgain to work.

Would be grateful for any help, I'm new to this... :)

Here is my Java code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class HigherOrLower {
public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println("Welcome to the Higher or Lower Game!");

    int cardOne;
    int cardTwo;
    String userGuess;
    String userInput;
    boolean playAgain = false;

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    do{

        do{
            Random rand = new Random();
            cardOne = rand.nextInt(13)+1;
            System.out.println("Card is: " + cardOne);
            System.out.print("(H)igher or (L)ower: ");
            userGuess = scan.nextLine();
            cardTwo = rand.nextInt(13)+1;       
        }while(!"H".equalsIgnoreCase(userGuess) || !"L".equalsIgnoreCase(userGuess));

        if(((cardOne > cardTwo) && (userGuess.equalsIgnoreCase("L"))) || ((cardTwo > cardOne) && (userGuess.equalsIgnoreCase("H")))){
            System.out.println("Card is: " + cardTwo);
            System.out.println("well done you are correct.");
            playAgain = true;
            cardOne = cardTwo;
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("You lose. The Card was: " + cardTwo);
            System.out.print("Play Again? (Y/N): ");
            userInput = scan.next();
            if (userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {
                playAgain = true;
            }
            else {
                playAgain = false;
            }
        }
    }while(playAgain);

    scan.close();
}
```

}

Comment: I think the condition that says `(!"H".equalsIgnoreCase(userGuess) || !"L".equalsIgnoreCase(userGuess))` should read `(!"H".equalsIgnoreCase(userGuess) && !"L".equalsIgnoreCase(userGuess))` - otherwise it will just always be true (every letter is either not H or not L - and most are both).  I haven't really looked for any other errors, but this one is kind of a biggie.

Comment: that's right. BTW quite of basic boolean logic:  !"H".equalsIgnoreCase(userGuess) && !"L".equalsIgnoreCase(userGuess) = !("H".equalsIgnoreCase(userGuess) || "L".equalsIgnoreCase(userGuess))

Comment: Thank you so much, it works! :D